# What does showInputDialog return?

Tags: java

I work on a project in Java for school, and I have a problem with `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`.

My question is: What does `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` return if I enter nothing into the field and then hit "OK"?

I tried to find it out by myself with this test-code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter:");
    if (test==""){
        System.out.println("Found it");
    }else{
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, as I said. It will print out the variable test, instead of the string "Found it".

What must I enter in the if-query in case I enter nothing in the field and then hit 'OK'?

Excuse my English, I'm Swiss.

Comment: It probably returns null

Comment: it returns user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

Comment: Indeed, the output will be the empty String `""` , the problem is how you compare the Strings .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter:");
        if (test==null){
            System.out.println("Found it");
        }else{
            System.out.println(test);
        }
    }
```